# Captured variable-like error in Parallel.For loop

Tags: c#, parallel.for

The following code section worked appropriately:

```
            Parallel.For(
                0, numberOfRunsNeeded, j => 
                {
                    var copyOfj = j;
                         
                    var researchItems = viewModel.ResearchItems[queryNumber].GetRange((int)(copyOfj * itemsAtOnce), Math.Min(itemsAtOnce, viewModel.ResearchItems[queryNumber].Count - (copyOfj * itemsAtOnce)));

                    var finalQuery = GetCorrectedQuery(query.BaseQuery, query.SQLVariants[copyOfi]);
                    if (researchItems.Count > 0)
                    {
                        finalQuery = GetCorrectedQueryWithResearchItems(finalQuery, researchItems, query.SQLVariants[copyOfi]);
                    }

                    PerformSingleRun(query, copyOfi, dataSource, finalQuery, copyOfj, viewModel);
                }
            );
```

This updated code shows captured variable-like errors - `finalQuery` comes back like the For loop is repeating the same value many times:

```
            Parallel.For(
                0, numberOfRunsNeeded, parallelOptionsWithMaxDegreeOfParallelism, j =>
                {
                    var copyOfj = j;

                    if (researchItemsPresent)
                    {
                        var researchItems = ViewModel.ResearchItems[queryNumber].GetRange(copyOfj * itemsAtOnce, Math.Min(itemsAtOnce, ViewModel.ResearchItems[queryNumber].Count - (copyOfj * itemsAtOnce)));
                        finalQuery = GetAdaptedBaseQueryWithResearchItemsInserted(finalQuery, researchItems, query.SQLVariants[copyOfi]);
                    }

                    PerformSingleRun(query, copyOfi, dataSource, finalQuery, copyOfj, viewModel);
                }
            );
```

As stated above, I already have working code - I'm just trying to understand what I did wrong in my revision. Full methods listed below:

---

Previous, working:

```
    public static void ProcessSingleQuery(int queryNumber, ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var query = new Query
        {
            Name = viewModel.QueryNames[queryNumber],
            BaseQuery = viewModel.BaseQueries[queryNumber],
            SelectedDatabases = viewModel.SelectedDatabases[queryNumber],
            SQLVariants = viewModel.SQLVariants[queryNumber],
            Usernames = viewModel.Usernames[queryNumber],
            Passwords = viewModel.Passwords[queryNumber],
            CSVFiles = viewModel.CSVFiles[queryNumber],
            CSVFileAliases = viewModel.CSVFileAliases[queryNumber],
            ColumnDelimiters = viewModel.ColumnDelimiters[queryNumber],
            HeaderRowsPresent = viewModel.HeaderRowsPresent[queryNumber],
            TextDelimiters = viewModel.TextDelimiters[queryNumber],
            ResearchItemColumnNumber = viewModel.ResearchItemColumnNumber[queryNumber]
        };


        for (var i = 0; i < query.SelectedDatabases.Count; i++)
        {
            var dataSource = GetDataSource(query.SelectedDatabases[i]);
            var itemsAtOnce = ViewModel.ItemsAtOnceBySQLVariant[query.SQLVariants[i]];
            if (query.SelectedDatabases[i].Equals("CSV"))
            {
                RefreshOrCreateSchemaIniFile(query);
                dataSource = query.CSVFiles[0].DirectoryName;
            }


            var numberOfRunsNeeded = Math.Max(
                (int)Math.Ceiling((double)viewModel.ResearchItems[queryNumber].Count / itemsAtOnce), 1
            );

            viewModel.QueryRunsCompletedMaximum += numberOfRunsNeeded;

            var copyOfi = i;

            Parallel.For(
                0, numberOfRunsNeeded, j => 
                {
                    var copyOfj = j;
                         
                    var researchItems = viewModel.ResearchItems[queryNumber].GetRange((int)(copyOfj * itemsAtOnce), Math.Min(itemsAtOnce, viewModel.ResearchItems[queryNumber].Count - (copyOfj * itemsAtOnce)));

                    var finalQuery = GetCorrectedQuery(query.BaseQuery, query.SQLVariants[copyOfi]);
                    if (researchItems.Count > 0)
                    {
                        finalQuery = GetCorrectedQueryWithResearchItems(finalQuery, researchItems, query.SQLVariants[copyOfi]);
                    }

                    PerformSingleRun(query, copyOfi, dataSource, finalQuery, copyOfj, viewModel);
                }
            );
        }

        GeneralTools.CombineAndDeleteQueryResults(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), query.Name);
        if (query.ResearchItemColumnNumber != 0)
        {
            CompileMissingItemsReport(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), query.Name, viewModel, queryNumber);
        }
    }
```

---

Revised, broken:

```
    public static void ProcessSingleQuery(int queryNumber, ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        var query = new Query
        {
            Name = ViewModel.QueryNames[queryNumber],
            BaseQuery = ViewModel.BaseQueries[queryNumber],
            SelectedDatabases = ViewModel.SelectedDatabases[queryNumber],
            SQLVariants = ViewModel.SQLVariants[queryNumber],
            Usernames = ViewModel.Usernames[queryNumber],
            Passwords = ViewModel.Passwords[queryNumber],
            CSVFiles = ViewModel.CSVFiles[queryNumber],
            CSVFileAliases = ViewModel.CSVFileAliases[queryNumber],
            ColumnDelimiters = ViewModel.ColumnDelimiters[queryNumber],
            HeaderRowsPresent = ViewModel.HeaderRowsPresent[queryNumber],
            TextDelimiters = ViewModel.TextDelimiters[queryNumber],
            ResearchItemColumnNumber = ViewModel.ResearchItemColumnNumber[queryNumber]
        };


        for (var i = 0; i < query.SelectedDatabases.Count; i++)
        {
            var finalQuery = GetAdaptedBaseQuery(query, query.SQLVariants[i]);
            var dataSource = GetDataSource(query.SelectedDatabases[i]);
            var itemsAtOnce = ViewModel.ItemsAtOnceBySQLVariant[query.SQLVariants[i]];

            if (query.SelectedDatabases[i].Contains("CSV"))
            {
                CreateSchemaIniFile(query);
                dataSource = query.CSVFiles[0].DirectoryName;
            }

            var researchItemsPresent = ViewModel.ResearchItems[queryNumber].Count > 0;
            var numberOfRunsNeeded = Math.Max(
                (int)Math.Ceiling((double)ViewModel.ResearchItems[queryNumber].Count / itemsAtOnce), 1
            );

            viewModel.QueryRunsCompletedMaximum += numberOfRunsNeeded;

            var copyOfi = i;

            var parallelOptionsWithMaxDegreeOfParallelism = new ParallelOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism =
                query.SQLVariants[i] == SQLVariant.Teradata ? 6 : -1
            };

            Parallel.For(
                0, numberOfRunsNeeded, parallelOptionsWithMaxDegreeOfParallelism, j =>
                {
                    var copyOfj = j;

                    if (researchItemsPresent)
                    {
                        var researchItems = ViewModel.ResearchItems[queryNumber].GetRange(copyOfj * itemsAtOnce, Math.Min(itemsAtOnce, ViewModel.ResearchItems[queryNumber].Count - (copyOfj * itemsAtOnce)));
                        finalQuery = GetAdaptedBaseQueryWithResearchItemsInserted(finalQuery, researchItems, query.SQLVariants[copyOfi]);
                    }

                    PerformSingleRun(query, copyOfi, dataSource, finalQuery, copyOfj, viewModel);
                }
            );
        }

        GeneralTools.CombineAndDeleteQueryResults(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), query.Name);
        if (query.ResearchItemColumnNumber != 0)
        {
            CompileMissingItemsReport(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), query.Name, queryNumber);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `finalQuery` in your closure is the same `finalQuery` as the outer scope, which you both read and write your parallel.for. `finalQuery = GetAdaptedBaseQueryWithResearchItemsInserted(finalQuery ...` that won't work.  Working examples have a local `finalQuery` variable.

Comment: @Wyck That's correct, thank you! It's baby's first race condition. If you submit that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why your broken version is broken

The problem appears to be two-fold:

First, you have a variable called `finalQuery` in an outer scope which you also use in a closure, specifically the one passed in as the body delegate of your `Parallel.For`, and is therefore the same variable in all iterations of your `Parallel.For`.

Second, you both read and write this `finalQuery` variable in that same `Parallel.For` body, notably with the code:

```
finalQuery = GetAdaptedBaseQueryWithResearchItemsInserted(finalQuery, ...)
```

...where you'll see you pass the current value of `finalQuery` as your base query.

The order in which the various iterations of that loop reach that line of code can change and depends on system architecture and processor load, causing a *race condition*.  Access to your variable is also not governed by a `lock`.

#### Why the other version worked

In your working version, `finalQuery` is a variable that is declared within and therefore entirely local to the `Parallel.For` body function.  This prevents any *iterations* from seeing values of `finalQuery` from other iterations.  And more importantly, each `finalQuery` is constructed from a common, invariant base query (`query.baseQuery`) with this code:

```
var finalQuery = GetCorrectedQuery(query.BaseQuery, ...)
```

And although you further adjust the value of `finalQuery` in the line below:

```
finalQuery = GetCorrectedQueryWithResearchItems(finalQuery, ...)
```

...this is fine because this `finalQuery` variable is local to your lambda function and its value is based solely on the previous line, and fortunately, *not* from varying values being written by other iterations of the `Parallel.For`, as was the case in your race condition.